# Highlight multiple characters in array with different colors

Tags: python, colors, highlight, colorama

I'm fairly new to python so I'm wondering if anyone could help with my issue. I have a program that is reading an array of numbers and replacing the 1's with green coloured circles and the 4's with yellow coloured circles. The issue I'm having is I would like for the array to print with the two changes applied but can only get it to print with one change applied, followed by the same array with the other change applied. How can I get the array to print with the two changes at once? Here's the code:

```
import time
from colorama import Fore

def highlight(text):
            return text.replace("1", "{}{}".format(Fore.GREEN, Fore.RESET)) + text.replace("4", "{}{}".format(Fore.YELLOW, Fore.RESET))

i = 0

while i <= 10:
   
    time.sleep(3)
   
    with open(r'./serial_data/generations.txt', 'r') as file:
 
        data = file.read()

        text = highlight(data)
       
            print(text)

            i = i+1
```

I'm aware this is happening because of the plus I have in the return line but this is the closest I can get it to achieve the required result. Anything else I've tried only results in errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you save the results of the first replacement to a variable, and passed that into the second replacement?

Comment: What if you do smth like `....Fore.RESET)).replace`

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `colorama`, don't know anything about it, and don't even have it installed, but I'm going to show you a better way to do it, anyway.

I think it's obvious this is for coloring the console text, and in that you have a big issue. The formats that this is going to add to your text is full of numbers. This means that as you go along replacing numbers, you are going to also start replacing chunks of the format that you injected.

The only way around this is with `regex`. However it becomes more complicated because you need to replace a single character with many characters, which means as the regex is rolling along we need to build a separate string that will be your final data. Getting everything to line up without losing any data is cumbersome.

This is well beyond an example.

```
import time, re
from colorama import Fore

#for finding digits that are not marked as a format
expr = re.compile(r'((?<!\[)\d+)')

#append all your formats to this `dict`
formats = {
    '1':f'{Fore.GREEN}{Fore.RESET}',
    '2':f'{Fore.RED}{Fore.RESET}',
    '3':f'{Fore.BLUE}{Fore.RESET}',
    '4':f'{Fore.YELLOW}{Fore.RESET}',
}

#engine  
def highlight(data:str) -> str:
    text, i = '', 0                             #starter kit
    for m in expr.finditer(data):               #iterate over entire string
        if fmt := formats.get(m.group(1)):      #determine if this number is a token
            text += (data[i:m.span()[0]] + fmt) #concatenate "tween" + format value
            i  = m.span()[1]                    #store last position for next iteration
    return text

#shenanigans?    
for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(3)
    
    with open(r'./serial_data/generations.txt', 'r') as file:
        text = highlight(file.read())
        print(text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this worked. One more thing though, I also wanted to replace the 2's with red in the array aswell as replacing 3's with blue but when I try following your steps which worked for replacing 2 characters it won't work for replacing 3 or more characters, it populates the array with some random letters and symbols.

Comment: @Paul_Pr1ce ~ I changed my code from the version you just posted. Try again with my better answer.